# Problems filtering columns that have many rows with a None value(Django database)

Tags: python, django, django-database

I am filtering a certain column in PostgreSQL database.

```
 n = Database.objects.values(column).count()
        for i in range(0, n):
            name = list(Database.objects.all().values_list(column, flat=True))[i]
```

There are 105 lines. From line 86 onwards the values are **None**. However, when querying line 43, the returned value is None, **although in the database this line is filled with a value**.

Strangely, **when I populate lines 86 onwards, the query on line 43 is correct** and does not return a None value.

I want to know if there is any problem when filtering columns that have many None values and why this might be happening

Comment: The ordering. The order of the return value is not guaranteed if no order is specified. Simply add `.order_by('id')`, and the result should match your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is any problem when filtering columns that have many None values

No, there is no problem with that.

---

A relational database contains sets of rows,
named "tables".

Sets are unordered. Yet you speak of values
starting at this or that offset, as though
we had a list of values where order matters.

I recommend that you order your result rows
so they appear in a reproducible sequence.
Use ORDER BY with the database,
and `sorted( ... )` for python expressions.